# Error compiling rpy2 on python3.4 due to -Werror=declaration-after-statement

Tags: python, gcc, compiler-errors, rpy2, python-3.4

I ran into an error compiling `rpy2` when trying to `pip install` it:

```
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:2376:3: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=declaration-after-statement]
```

(and many more like it)

This is the call that Python made to the compiler:

```
gcc -pthread -Werror=declaration-after-statement -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DR_INTERFACE_PTRS=1 -DHAVE_POSIX_SIGJMP=1 -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND=1 -DCSTACK_DEFNS=1 -DHAS_READLINE=1 -I./rpy/rinterface -I/home/hen/miniconda3/envs/fitts/include/python3.4m -I/usr/share/R/include -c ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.o
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some googling, I determined that the problem was the `-Werror=declaration-after-statement` flag. Trying to figure out where this flag came from. I eventually came across [this Python issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue21121):

> I got an error while rebuilding a module for 3.4. This was a ISO C90 error but setup.py explicitely adds `-std=c99` to the gcc parameters, and indeed it is used.
>
> `fifo.h:114:5: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=declaration-after-statement]
>   uint32_t ofs = fifo->write_count - fifo->write_offset;`
>
> However, Py 3.4 seems to add `-Werror=declaration-after-statement` also for extension modules. This should not happen (said also Yhg1s in `#python`).

Until the fix makes its way to you, this can be solved by running

```
export CFLAGS="-Wno-error=declaration-after-statement"
```

before running `pip install` or `python setup.py install`.

Comment: Probably the same issue here: https://bitbucket.org/lgautier/rpy2/issue/203/problems-building-rpy2-hg-repository-on . The fix should be in Python 3.4.2.

Comment: I can confirm that 3.4.2 fixes the issue.